# Magento 2.4.1 categories product disappear automatically

Tags: magento2.4

I am facing this problem since I update to the latest Magento 2.4.1 I have elastic search running but  categories product disappear automatically and I have to run the reindex command this is happening 5,6 times in a day I have 3500 SKU on my website
it shows WE CAN'T FIND PRODUCTS MATCHING THE SELECTION.
after running reindex command it starts working again for sometime
kindly help

Comment: can you check the log file getting any error ?

Comment: No error in any log file

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution maybe it helps you

I am running 3 sites in 1 AWS server and elastic search need the prefix for all sites so that I don't confuse with all sites

here is a quick tip

go to admin > Catalog > catalog > Catalog Search > Elasticsearch Index Prefix

fill this column with your site name 
so all three different sites have different names and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Once a day all products would disappear from fronted and would require reindexing.
I realised I had used the same Elastic Search creditials on a testing subdomain that had no products.
Once I changed those creditials, the problem went away.